# New to python, need guide on ip address

Tags: python, networking

hello recently i brought a course on udemy and i wanted to make my current job easier by using python.
below is the code i wanted to use but im not very sure how to fix it.
i am also not very sure if ip address should be stored as int or str.
input would be something like 192.168.1.1
i would like to decrease this input by 1 to 192.168.1.0
i tried googling but i cant seem to understand as other answers are not related to ip address.

```
wanip = str(input("please key in WAN IP address:"))

print(wanip - 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ipaddress.IPv4Address`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ipaddress.html#arithmetic-operators):

```
import ipaddress

str(ipaddress.IPv4Address("192.168.1.1") - 1)
```

Output:

```
'192.168.1.0'
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply.
but wouldn't this make the input always be 192.168.1.1?
i would like the user of my script or program to be able to key in the ip address themselves

Answer (score 0):

```
import ipaddress

wanip = str(ipaddress.IPv4Address(input("Please key in WAN ip address")) - 1)

print(wanip)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.